# How to get autocompletion for Motoko in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, motoko

I am learning the Motoko language. This is a screenshot from the video I am learning, for instance there are suggestions for the function `now()`, although, I had downloaded the Motoko extension by Difinity Foundation.

[image]

and this is what I have.

[image]

How do I get autocompletion?